# Showing certain sets are subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Let $H = \{x \in G: x = x'\}$. Prove $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

Suppose $a, b, c \in H.$ Since $G$ is a group and $H \subseteq G,$ $a(bc) = (ab)c.$  So, the operation on $H$ is associative. Also, $xx  = e,$ so $H$ contains identity and it's given that every element in $H$ has an inverse. Thus $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

> Let $n$ be a fixed integer, and let $H = \{x \in G: x^n = e\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

We show associativity as described above and the identity is given. If $n$ is even, then every element in $H$ is its own inverse. If $n$ is odd, $x = e.$ Since $e^2 = e,$ every element in $H$  is its own inverse. Thus $H$ is a subgroup of $G.$

Please, see if that works.

Comment: Is $x' = x^{-1}$? I guess it is from your assumptions...

Comment: @ equin, yes that's right.

Comment: Should there be an additional condition, such as $G$ is abelian?  These results do not hold in general groups.  For instance, in the dihedral group $D_4$ (symmetries of a square), $4$ reflections, a $180$ degree rotation, and the identity are all self-inverse; but this subset (of $6$ elements) is definitely not a subgroup.

Comment: @ paw88789, yes $G$ is supposed to be abelian. Forgot to specify that.

Answer (score 1):

In an abelian group, we have that if $x=x^{-1}$ and $y=y^{-1}$, then $(xy)^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}=yx=xy$.  So $H$ is closed.  Clearly $H$ contains the identity and inverses.  So it is a subgroup.  Abelian is needed (see my comment).

Answer (score 0):

Your second proof doesn't seem to be corrent. It is not true that if $n$ is even then every element in $H$ is its own inverse. Take, for instance, $\mathbb{Z}_12$ under addition and the element $3$. Then $3 \times 3=0$ but $3 + 3 = 6 \neq 0$.

For these types of problems, I recommend the subgroup test, which works as follows:

Let $G$ be a group and $H$ a subset of $G$. Then $H$ is a subgroup if and only if:

(i) for all $a,b \in H$, $ab \in H$.

(ii) $e \in H$

(iii) for all $a \in H$, $a^{-1} \in H$.

Comment: Do we show associativity like we do for the first problem? Also, $e$ is given for free, right? So, then all that's left to show is that every element in $H$ has an inverse, correct?

Comment: Yes, associativity is shown just the way you did it. Aha!! You made the same mistake that I made: the fact that (i) and (iii) imply (ii) is true if and only if the set $H$ is nonempty. So you could replace condition (ii) by $H \neq \phi$, but then to show this the easiest element to use tends to be $e$ so in the end it doesn't matter...
Yes, you need to show every element has an inverse. It isn't true that the inverse of $x$ needs to be $x$ though... And remember: you need to show the inverse is in $H$, not just that it exists!!

Comment: $x^n = e \to x^nx^{-n} = x^{-n} \to e = x^{-n} \to x^n = x^{-n},$ so $x^n$ is its own inverse meaning every $x$ in $H$ is its own inverse. Is that correct?

Comment: Mmmmm... no. Recall that the inverse of an element $x$ is an element $y$ such that $x y = e$. Here you have:
$x^n = e \implies x x^{n-1} = e$ so $x^{-1} = x^{n-1}$.